# Hibernate <-> H2. Float mapping exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa, h2

I have Spring-boot(with `Kotlin`) project and for testing purposes I'm using H2 database.

`Field` in my entity

```kotlin
  @Column
  var cargoWeightAmount: Float? = null
```

`DDL` part from `flyway` script

```sql
create table pi_picargo_awb (..., cargo_weight_amount float, ...)
```

If I have `hibernate.ddl-auto: update` there is no problems, mapping works fine. But if I have `hibernate.ddl-auto: validate` then I'm getting this error -> `Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [cargo_weight_amount] in table [pi_picargo_awb]; found [real (Types#REAL)], but expecting [float4 (Types#FLOAT)]`

I tried to replace `float` with `real`, `float4` it did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using BigDecimal type for entity and Number type for database